"How to Remove Formatting from Only the Last Text Node in a Rich Text Editor in React?"
I'm developing a rich text editor in React, and I'm facing a challenge with text formatting. Specifically, when users apply bold formatting to a portion of text, I want to ensure that subsequent text does not inherit that formatting when they continue typing.
Current Behavior:
For example, if a user types:
"Today is sunday"
and then applies bold formatting to "sunday", the HTML structure would look like this:
Today is sunday
If the user continues typing and adds " and", the text now appears as:
Today is sunday and
When the user selects "and" and clicks to remove the bold formatting, the current implementation causes both "sunday and" to lose their bold formatting, resulting in:
"Today is sunday and"
Desired Behavior:
I want to modify the behavior so that when the user selects "and" and removes the bold formatting, only "and" should lose the bold formatting, while "sunday" remains bold. The expected result should be:
Today is sunday and
const toggleFormat = (tag, input = null) => {
  const selection = editableRef.current.ownerDocument.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      const selectedText = range.toString();

      if (selectedText.length === 0) {
          return; // No text selected, do nothing
      }

      let isAlreadyFormatted = isTextFormatted(range, tag);

      if (isAlreadyFormatted) {
            // Remove formatting
            const parent = range.startContainer.parentNode;
            console.log(parent.startContainer)
            if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === tag) {
                // Replace the parent element with a plain text node containing its text content
                const textNode = document.createTextNode(parent.textContent);
                parent.parentNode.replaceChild(textNode, parent);
            }
      } else {
          // Add formatting

          const element = document.createElement(tag);
          console.log(element,tag)
          if(tag === 'a' && input == null) {
            openLinkOverlay();
            return
          }

          if(input){
            element.href = input
          }

          element.textContent = selectedText;
          
          range.deleteContents(); // Remove the selected text from the document
          range.insertNode(element); // Insert the newly created formatted element

      }
      // Update the output div with the formatted markdown
      const markDown = TurndownService.turndown(editableRef.current.innerHTML);
      const formattedMarkdown = markDown.replace(/\n(?!\n)/g, '<br>');
      divRef.current.innerHTML = formattedMarkdown;
  }
};


I implemented a rich text editor in React where users can apply bold formatting to selected text. My current implementation allows users to toggle bold formatting using a button. However, I noticed that when users continue typing after applying bold formatting, the subsequent text inherits the bold style unintentionally. For instance, if a user types "Today is sunday" and then applies bold to "sunday", the resulting HTML is:
Today is sunday
If they continue typing and add " and", the HTML becomes:
Today is sunday and
When they select "and" and click to remove the bold formatting, both "sunday" and "and" lose their bold formatting, which is not the desired behavior.
What I Expected:
I expected that when a user selects only "and" and removes the bold formatting, only "and" would lose its bold style, while "sunday" would remain bold. The desired outcome should look like this:
Today is sunday and
I want to ensure that the formatting removal only affects the selected text, without altering the formatting of adjacent text that may have been previously formatted. Feel free to adjust any part of this response to better fit your style or specific situation!

Have you considered using one of the many existing WYSIWYG editor libraries that exist for React? This is likely not something worth implementing by hand.
